# jQuery Masonry not reloading on certain calls?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins, jquery-masonry

The masonry plugin seems to not reload on certain calls, it might just be something missing in the code, but I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. Here's my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery(".pics-hidden").hide();

jQuery('#menu1').click(function() {
      var menu = $(this).attr('menuref');
      jQuery(".pics").fadeOut(0).filter("[imageref='" + menu + "']").fadeIn(0);
      jQuery('#projectimages').masonry('reload');
});

jQuery('#menu2').click(function() {
      var menu = $(this).attr('menuref');
      jQuery(".pics").fadeOut(0).filter("[imageref='" + menu + "']").fadeIn(0);
      jQuery('#projectimages').masonry('reload');
});

jQuery('.pics').click(function() {
      jQuery('#div'+jQuery(this).attr('rarget')).addClass('pics').removeClass('#div'+jQuery(this).attr('rarget')).delay(600).fadeIn(400);
      jQuery('#projectimages').masonry('reload');
       });

jQuery('.close').click(function() {
      jQuery('#div'+jQuery(this).attr('larget')).removeClass('pics').addClass('.pics-hidden').removeClass('#div'+jQuery(this).attr('larget')).fadeOut(200);
      jQuery('#projectimages').masonry('reload'); 
      return false;      
});
});
```

The bottom 2 calls work fine and reload successfully, but for some reason the top 2 calls (including the filter) don't seem to reload the masonry plugin.
Can't figure it out at all.

Comment: maybe the calls right before are having issues,  if you replaced masonry with `alert(1)` do you get a pop up?

Comment: You have a jsfiddle or online sandbox so one can check the whole script, data-attributes and CSS?

Comment: @Systembolaget here's a quick mock-up of the template on my server so you can view the code in it's entirety: http://nealfletcher.co.uk/testing-testing/

Comment: @user1374796 - I am sorry, I have trouble understanding the problem, on my computer the behavior seems predicted . can you explain again what do you want it to make as opposed to what it makes now ??

Comment: @ObmerkKronen well the filters work fine, if you click 'Lorum' at the top it will filter the content correctly, but after clicking the masonry is supposed to reload and re-distribute the content left towards the top left of the page, and not floating where they were before, if that makes sense? Basically after clicking the filter at the top, the masonry plugin isn't reloading, but it should.

Comment: @user1374796 - well as far as I know ( and I might be wrong) the masonry does not have a filtering function - but it´s big brother Isotope...

Comment: @ObmerkKronen yes I know, the filtering is not the issue though, that bit of the code is working fine. It's merely the .masonry('reload') that isn't working on the top 2 filter calls, and I can't figure out why

Comment: There's something very odd in your whole Masonry setup. Normally, you nest all content in each .item (.masonry-brick); like images, videos, text. But in your #container (#projectimages), you have divs containing text that, by having them there, are then part of Masonry's layout logic. That's not the usual way to set this up. I have the feeling, this is part of the problem. Instead, you can just expand each Masonry .item on click to .show() additional content, for example.